# Python numerical precision

Tags: python, numeric, exponentiation

How does Python handle big numbers? I was working with exponentials and exponential notation returned me `inf` but when I used `pow` function I got it rigth.

Particularly, I had: `1e1000 -> inf` and `pow(10, 1000)` equals to a big number.

Comment: Python has infinite precision integers, but not floating point. `1e1000` is floating point.

Comment: If you need arbitrary precision floating point numbers consider the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module.